# Cannot call javascript methods from java

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, webview, android-webview

I cannot call a JavaScript method from Java!

I included this in the main java file:

```
 JavaScriptInterface jsInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(this);
        cordova_webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        cordova_webview.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "JSInterface");

@Override 
protected void onPause() { 
    super.onPause(); 
    cordova_webview.loadUrl("javascript:punish()");
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
}
```

BUT I get this error in logacat:

```
07-15 17:25:18.490: D/CORDOVA_ACTIVITY(6422): onPause
07-15 17:25:18.495: D/CordovaLog(6422): null: Line 1 : Uncaught ReferenceError: punish is not defined
07-15 17:25:18.495: E/Web Console(6422): Uncaught ReferenceError: punish is not defined at null:1
```

the method is in index.js, which is included in the html.

However I tried to include the method in the html through a `<script>` tag and it's executing, but only after onResume!

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this, in your javascript code, set:

```
window.fn = punish;
```

and then call window.fn() from your android code:

```
cordova_webview.loadUrl("javascript:window.fn()");
```

'fn' is not special here. We are just trying to make your function
visible or accessible. 'window' object is already accessible, so
we just set a reference to your function there. So, for example,

```
window.myFunc1 = punish;
```

.. would be fine too. I'm not entirely sure why this is required,
but I'm posting this here anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is what made the difference and now it works fine:
window.fn = punish in my JS code, and then call window.fn() from your android code